# PHP- How to get all rows from a table satisfying a condition?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've a table **invitation** with coloumns **toemail**, **fromemail**, **send**
I need to print **toemail** & **fromemail** from all rows having valid **send=1**

This is the code that I'm using

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT fromemail,toemail FROM invitations WHERE sent = 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $row['toemail'];
    echo $row['fromemail];
}
?>
```

But this prints only the first row which satisfying the condition.
Help me to get the php code please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to make database queries using PHP? Do you know how to make SQL queries using `WHERE ...` clauses? What is the problem in combining the two?

Comment: @deceze: I'm not good in php. I'm seeking help of stackoverflow for all my needs. What i know about my question is added. Please see the edited question

Comment: Well yes, because you're only fetching the first row. Please [read the manual](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) or tutorials or a book demonstrating how to work with `mysql_` in PHP. [BTW, don't use mysql anymore. It's deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)

Comment: @deceze: can you please help me to make necessary corrections in the code that i gave? Will it work if i change the "if" to "while" ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT fromemail,toemail FROM invitations WHERE sent = 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
           echo $row['toemail'];
           echo $row['fromemail];
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Edwin, I'm not good in php please see my edited question and help me to get the corrections that i should make in my code.

Comment: How can I do this with prepared statements?

Answer (score -1):

You can either use following -

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT fromemail,toemail FROM invitations WHERE sent = 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0)
{
    $result = mysql_result($query);
    foreach($result in $row) {
           echo $row->toemail;
           echo $row->fromemail;
    }
}
```

P.S. - MYSQL extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Reference - http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated